# How do you get fgrep to find the literal "--help"?

Tags: grep, options, arguments

```
fgrep --help | fgrep "--help"
```

returns just the whole fgrep --help, how do I return just the lines that have the literal "--help" in them?

The quotes don't do anything, nor does `\-\-help`.

Comment: I meant \-\-help

Comment: `fgrep -- --help`

Comment: Yes! does fgrep -- take every argument literally?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 Escaping the hyphen with a backslash is useless because you want the protection for the command (`fgrep`), not for the shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can use

```
fgrep -- --help
```

to achieve this. The man page mentions

```
fgrep -e --help
```

Quote from http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grep:

> -e pattern
>       Specify a pattern used during the search of the input: an input line is selected if it matches any of the specified patterns. This
>   option is most useful when multiple -e options are used to specify
>   multiple patterns, or when a pattern begins with a dash (‘-’).

Answer (score 5):

Alternate solution: use the `-e` option, as suggested by the man page ("to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen"):

```
fgrep -e --help
```